# Costs in explain queries in Vertica

Tags: output, vertica, explain

may I ask what exactly the costs in explain output are? Are they combied, summed (or something else) from several metrics like IO, RAM etc. or they are one specific metric?

e.g. +-SELECT  LIMIT 10 [Cost: 282K, Rows: 10]

Thank you
Martin

Answer (score 1):

It's actually [documented here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/QueryManagement/QueryPlans/QueryPlanCostEstimation.htm), although maybe not as exact as you would like.

> The query optimizer chooses a query plan based on cost estimates. The
>   query optimizer uses information from a number of sources to develop
>   potential plans and determine their relative costs. These include:
>
> - Number of table rows
> - Column statistics, including: number of distinct    values (cardinality), minimum/maximum values, distribution of values,    and
>     disk space usage
> - Access path that is likely to require fewest I/O    operations, and lowest CPU, memory, and network usage
> - Available eligible projections
> - Join options: join types (merge versus hash    joins), join order
> - Query predicates Data segmentation across cluster    nodes

Comment: Thank you for your response :) I've already read this and, yes, I would like more exact information about the costs.